# Angular TicTacToe Project RangeError

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Currently working on an Angular TicTacToe project.I am running Angular 17.0.4..I am having a Range Error. Maximum call stack size exceeded. I changed all instances of AppComponent to SquareComponent. I previously had an error

```
✘ [ERROR] TS2305: Module '"./app/app.component"' has no exported member 'AppComponent'. [plugin angular-compiler]
    src/main.server.ts:2:9:
      2 │ import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
        ╵          ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ✘ [ERROR] TS2305: Module '"./app/app.component"' has no exported member 'AppComponent'. [plugin angular-compiler]
    src/main.ts:3:9:
      3 │ import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
        ╵          ~~~~~~~~~~~~ ✘ [ERROR] No matching export in "src/app/app.component.ts" for import "AppComponent"
    src/main.server.ts:2:9:
      2 │ import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

app.component.ts
```

from ....

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-square',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class SquareComponent {
  title = 'TicTacToeApp';
}
```

I have tried to implement a previous fix of naming all AppComponents to SquareComponent and changing the selector to app-square and renaming app-root to app square.

Comment: could you please replicate the issue in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1da5ye?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter) and update in the question!

Comment: main.ts is still looking for app.component to bootstrap your application.

Comment: I changed the AppComponent in main.ts to SquareComponent as well

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you are using NX, we need to create components using `nx console` we need to generate a standalone component named square, then we need to import square component to app component in the imports array
2. after importing we can add square component to the root component by giving `<app-square></app-square>` inside the `app.component.html` so that you can start coding the tic tac toe application inside the square component.
3. After this I ran npm run start and the application worked fine!

app ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { SquareComponent } from './square/square.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, SquareComponent],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'TicTacToeApp';
}
```

app html

```
<app-square></app-square> <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

square ts

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-square',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './square.component.html',
  styleUrl: './square.component.css'
})
export class SquareComponent { }
```

square html

```
<p>square works!</p>
```